# A question on spin of an electron

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spin

Can an electron have zero spin? 
In para hydrogen, since the nuclei have opposite spins, the they add up to 0.

So is it true that one electron can have zero spin?

Comment: No, it can't.$\,$

Comment: Note that your example (para hydrogen) has two electrons, not one.

Comment: @VicLineal para/ortho hydrogen is about *nuclear* spin. Number of electrons does not matter there.

Comment: Welp, brain fart on my behalf.

Number of spin particles is still relevant to the OP's misunderstanding: note that your example (para hydrogen) has two particles with spin, not one. [The fact that both electrons and hydrogen nuclei are fermions is what makes both cases comparable.]

Answer (score 5):

No, electrons (and other [leptons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton)) are fermions and therefore must have half-integer spin. It is possible to couple the spin of several electrons together to obtain an integer total electron spin. Depending on the total electron spin of the atom or molecule the states are referred to as singlet, doublet, triplet, etc. for $S=0,1/2,1$, etc.

The hydrogen molecule has 2 electrons and the total electron spin can thus be zero (singlet) or 1 (triplet). The ground state of hydrogen is a singlet state, which is the case for most molecules, a notable exception is the oxygen molecule which has a triplet electronic ground state.

It is important to realise that the terms *para* and *ortho* have nothing to do with the **electronic** spin, but are used to distinguish between two different total **nuclear** spin values, para hydrogen has $I=0$ and ortho hydrogen has $I=1$.